# c# wpf public static control

Tags: c#, wpf

In code, I create a:

```
public static Button button1 = new Button();
```

and add it to a *Canvas*, and I can access the *Button* anywhere in any class in my code, but I can't figure out how to do this in *XAML*.

Basically I want to access my controls in any class, and I can do that if I create them in code, but not in *XAML*.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Why you need access your control from anywhere.... and in WPF ??

Comment: See [How to: Make Data Available for Binding in XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748857.aspx) where one can bind to other controls in Xaml. HTH

Comment: do not use a public static control property.

Comment: Organization, and so I don't have to pass the Button (and many other controls) as a parameter for a method in an outside class.

Comment: I understand this isn't necessarily a best practice, I would just like to do it for my own project.

Comment: I would suggest not trying to access the controls directly (winforms approach) and use the built in data binding with an MVVM pattern.  If you don't - your app is going to suffer.....

Answer (score 2):

With the following class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static System.Windows.Controls.Button GlobalButton {get; set;}

    static TestClass()
    {
        GlobalButton = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
        GlobalButton.Content = "Button1";
    }
}
```

You can use following *XAML*:

```
<Border Child="{x:Static MemberType=local:TestClass, Member=GlobalButton}" />
```

But, **I highly recommend you do not use this method** and find another way to do whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: amen to the warning, maybe you can find a way of *not* spelling a public static field with a lower case b? I know, you don't want to use the class name... still...

Comment: @codesparkle: Man, after you pointed it out, it started bugging me as well... I had to change it...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to give the control an x:name in the XAML and access it by that name in the code behind.   If you want to access them from ANY class then I am not sure you can do that in XAML as the XAML is more just associated with a single code behind.  If you need other classes to access the control then you would need to expose it as a  property in the code behind.  But why do you need to access a UI control from another class?

Comment: I just have a massive amount of code, and I want to keep it all organized in separate classes really is what it comes down to.

Comment: I have similar situation about this ,what I want,is to have a global control which was used for output my app's state or exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reference the object declared in XAML from anywhere, you might wan't to check out this interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.ixamlnameresolver.aspx

With this you should be able to resolve any object in a given XAML namescope by x:name